# Django - Export ASCII CSV

Tags: python, django, export-to-csv

I want to export a CSV-file encoded in ASCII but the default is UTF-8
if I encode the strings i get the bytecode written in the csv (b'String')

```
 response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
 response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="datev_export.csv"'
 writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter=";",)
 row = ['some', 'strings']
 writer.writerow(first_row)
 return response
```

So how can I encode my string to ASCII without the leading b'' ?

Comment: Your code does not produce the problem for me with Django 1.9 on Python 3. The CSV file does not contain the `b""` prefix, and the default encoding is ascii. Post the code and related data that produces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the encode method of strings like

```
"asdf".encode("ascii")
```

for bytes there is the decode method for getting things back like

```
b"asdf".decode("ascii")
```